# When to use 想 versus 喜欢?

Tags: meaning, characters

Could someone please give we a hint when to use either of those?!

My take is that 想 is used for actions and 喜欢 for things!? Am I right?

Answer (score 11):

In short, `想` means "think (of)" when followed by noun phrases or clauses, and "want to" when followed by verb phrases, while `喜欢` simply means "like / be fond of" in all cases.

Some details:

1. When followed by nouns/pronouns,

   - `想` means "think of / consider" or "miss", for example:

     > 我在想你 = I am missing you; 我在想这个问题 = I am considering this question.
   - `喜欢` means "like", for example:

     > 我喜欢你 = I like you
2. When followed by verb phrases,

   - `想` means "want to (do)", for example:

     > 我想吃鱼 = I want to eat fish
   - `喜欢` means "like to (do)" or "like (doing)", expressing non-momentary preference, hence not "would like to (do)", for example:

     > 我喜欢吃鱼 = I like eating fish
3. When followed by clauses,

   - `想` means "think (that)", for example:

     > 我想他不会来了 = I think (that) he won't come.

     Two relevant notes here:

     a. When `想要` is followed by clauses, it doesn't mean "think (that)", but "want A to do", where A is the subject of the following clause, for example:

     > 我想要他唱 = I want him to sing.

     BTW, a few native speakers may feel that `想要` in this usage is interchangeable with `想`.

     b. When `不想（要)`, in which "要" can be omitted, is followed by clauses, it doesn't mean "not think (that)", but "not want A to do", where A is the subject of the following clause, for example:

     > 我不想（要）你来 = I do not want you to come.
   - `喜欢` means "like it that", for example:

     > 我喜欢你这样做 = I like it that you do it this way

Comment: The answer by @user3306356 reminded me that this answer lacked a brief summary at the beginning. Thanks for that.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed  answer. These permutations in meaning  had puzzeld me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Because I find the other answers a little overwhelming and unclear I'm going to add my own two-cents:

[and the reason for my explanation being based *completely* on the confusion found in OP's question]

## 想 is just a shortened form of 想要 meaning "to want"

## 喜欢 means "to like"

·I like chocolate = 我喜欢巧克力

·I want to eat chocolate = 我想吃巧克力

Answer (score 4):

想 has several meanings:

1. think(想法)
2. suppose(想来)
3. miss(想念)
4. want to(想要)

喜欢 as a verb, it means to like or to love.

Answer (score 2):

We use想for the meaning of thinking,as 我想去中国 I want to go to China.
We use喜欢for the meaning of like,as 我喜欢中国 I like China.

Answer (score 1):

想 means think of (something or doing something)

喜欢 means to like (something or doing something or someone).

To answer your question,

想 isn't necessarily used for actions, it could also be "thinking of something or someone"

喜欢 isn't necessarily used for things, it could also be "like" doing something"